# How to pull & merge particular folder, file from other repo

Tags: mercurial

I have few questions and i would appreciate your help:

1. Say, i need specific folders  from another repo merged into my repo/working dir. How would i do properly?
2. If i pull anothers repo and then merge. Afterwards, realizing this is not working, so i call 'hg update -C'. Did this cleaned my repo from the changes i pulled from another repo that i released is not what i need?
3. Can i do a pessimistic merge where it only adds and updates, but not deletes?

Thanks for helping learn Mercurial

Margots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would just copy the needed files and folders from the other repo and commit them.  You could technically do what you want as a merge but it's a manual, error-prone, finicky process.
2. If you haven't committed your merge `update -C` will abandon the merge.  Do `update -C <myVersion>` to get the specific version you want.
3. This would be a messy process (see 1.) and I wouldn't bother.  If there are problems you can always revert your file to a previous version.